# JNI - Can't load classes compiled with netbeans

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying to load java classes in JNI. I have a test class written and compiled with NetBeans(tried version 7 and 7.1.2). My C program fails to load the test class compiled with NetBeans however, if I compile the same code using `javac` the class loads just fine.
I only have one version of JDK installed on my system.
I had done this same process before and everything worked fine. I recently re-installed my OS(Windows XP) and noticed this isn't working. What could be wrong?
This is what NetBeans outputs when compiling:

```
> D:\atoMerz\jTest\build\built-jar.properties Created dir:
> D:\atoMerz\jTest\build\classes Created dir:
> D:\atoMerz\jTest\build\empty Created dir:
> D:\atoMerz\jTest\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output Compiling 1
> source file to D:\atoMerz\jTest\build\classes compile: Created dir:
> D:\atoMerz\jTest\dist Copying 1 file to D:\atoMerz\jTest\build Nothing
> to copy. Building jar: D:\atoMerz\jTest\dist\jTest.jar To run this
> application from the command line without Ant, try: java -jar
> "D:\atoMerz\jTest\dist\jTest.jar" jar: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0
> seconds)
```

Comment: We need more information, which OS is it. you can also paste the commands netbeans does to compile the project (look in the console).

Comment: The error messages when you try to load the class using JNI from the C program would also help

Comment: The only wild guess I can make at this point is that netbeans is using java 7, while the command line is using java 6

Comment: @Petesh There's is no error code/message. I use the JNI FindClass method to load the class. If this method fails it returns `NULL`. If there's a way to get an error code can you please say?

Comment: @Petesh I have JDK 7 installed. I don't think the javac command is from java 6. I don't even have java 6 installed on the system.

Comment: That's why it is referred to as a 'wild guess'. This isn't something so fundamental as a classpath issue? you don't have it set to point to the jar, but when you javac, it only yields .class files, and the current working directory is implicitly in CLASSPATH if the variable is unset

Comment: @Petesh Not using the `.jar` file at this point. I'm setting the class path to be the classes folder of my NetBeans project and trying to load the class from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29228/discussion-between-petesh-and-atomerz)

Comment: "There's is no error code/message.". That can only mean that you aren't checking for exceptions after calling `FindClass()`. So do that.

Comment: @EJP Checking for exceptions or not should have no effect on the code that throws them. However I *did*add a try-catch block and still got nothing. Even tried to pass in junk as class name and still no exception. I wonder if I have to do something to somehow enable exceptions or something like that.

Comment: @AtoMerZ Checking for exceptions tells you *why* the code that throws them threw them. Without that, debugging is just a guessing game. That's why they get thrown. Either the method returned non-null or it threw an exception. Which is it?

Comment: @EJP, I think you misunderstood. So I re-state clearly. I **did** check for exceptions, **No** exception was thrown, yet the method **did** return `NULL`. It seems to me that exceptions are disabled by default, since passing in junk as class name still didn't raise exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing JDK 6 solved the problem.
But I still don't know why it wouldn't work with JDK 7.